# Drag and draw border in WM_MOUSEMOVE?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to implement a feature where the user presses the left mouse button down, drags a mouse somewhere, and it draws a "bordered rectangle" (rectangle without any fill that shows what's underneath, so basically just a border).

I have *something* working with this code:

```
         case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
              if (draw) {
                  endX = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
                  endY = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
                  hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
                  SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH));
                  Rectangle(hdc, startX, startY, endX, endY);
                  ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
              }
            break;
```

(draw is set to true when WM_LBUTTONDOWN is fired and set to false when WM_LBUTTONUP is fired).

Here's what it looks like. I basically want this, without the black lines inside, and possibly a thicker border.
[image]

The problem I'm having is I'm not able to figure out how to redraw what was "lost" inside the rectangle region. I think I should be using InvalidateRect instead of Rectangle but again, not sure how to redraw in WM_PAINT. Perhaps I should be approaching this an entirely different way? This is my first time using Winapi.

Comment: Typically when rubber-banding (drawing a box in this manner) one doesn't pain a solid colour over the background, but instead XORs the line with the background. To erase the line, it's a simple matter of XORing the same line again, at which point the original background returns.

Comment: I've tried setting the ROP2 to XORPEN before drawing the rectangle as in my code above, which sounds similar to what you're saying, but haven't had success with that function:

                  SetROP2(hdc, R2_XORPEN);

Comment: Have you looked at the example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145184(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Who owns that window? If it is yours then you do the following: 1. When the mouse goes down, remember the coordinate. 2. When the mouse moves paint the image over the previous rectangle, and then paint the new rectangle on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to David Heffernan I have a solution:

```
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
      if (draw) {
          // Get current mouse position
          endX = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
          endY = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);

          // Paint over previous rectangle
          hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
          hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
          hbmOld = (HBITMAP) SelectObject(hdcMem, screenshot);
          BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, fullW, fullH, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
          SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmOld);

          // Change to NULL_BRUSH (no fill)
          hBrush = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
          hOldBrush = (HBRUSH) SelectObject(hdc, hBrush);

          // Change to red pen
          hPen = GetStockObject(DC_PEN);
          hOldPen = SelectObject(hdc, hPen);
          SetDCPenColor(hdc, RGB(255,0,0));

          // Draw new rectangle
          Rectangle(hdc, startX, startY, endX, endY);

          // Restore original brush and brush
          SelectObject(hdc, hOldBrush);
          SelectObject(hdc, hOldPen);

          ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
          DeleteDC(hdcMem);
      }
    break;
```

Basically I save a screenshot of the window before drawing begins (in a bitmap called screenshot) and draw over the entire screen every time mouse moves. startX and startY are set once when WM_LBUTTONDOWN is fired. I think it's extremely inefficient to redraw the entire screen but I couldn't get it to work if I just partially drew over the area that needed redrawing. I might come back to this if I feel that performance is an issue but from my testing it seemed very smooth.